# API request was working through localhost but not working through web server

Tags: android

I am trying to fetch json data to my android app. When I was using local server it was working fine but when I migrated it to a web server it is not working. I have checked the api links in browser and they are giving the data in browser

This is what I'm getting in error logs:

```
E/com.newrelic.android: TransactionStateUtil: Attempting to convert network exception java.net.SocketTimeoutException to error code.
E/com.newrelic.android: HttpsURLConnectionExtension: java.io.IOException: CountingInputStream: input stream cannot be null
E/final123: http://shopcite.rf.gd/shopcite/fetch_hotels.php?city=mathura&origin=18.5914802,73.7075401
```

Last line is the one which is getting the data. And I am fetching the result in android through AsyncTask so no work is being done on main thread.

```
public class hotelList extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HotelModel>>{
    @Override
    protected List<HotelModel> doInBackground(String... strings) {
        List<HotelModel> hotelModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (!dataSet) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
            jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(HotelURL + CONSTANTS.city+"&origin=" + CONSTANTS.origin);
            Log.e("final123", HotelURL + CONSTANTS.city+"&origin=" + CONSTANTS.origin);
            dataSet = true;
            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONArray listArray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                    for (int i = 0; i < listArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject hotelObject = listArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        HotelModel hotelModel = new HotelModel();
                        hotelModel.setName(hotelObject.getString("name"));
                        hotelModel.setAddr(hotelObject.getString("addr"));
                        hotelModel.setCateg(hotelObject.getString("categ"));
                        hotelModel.setImg(CONSTANTS.server_domain+hotelObject.getString("image"));
                        hotelModel.setPrice(hotelObject.getInt("price"));
                        hotelModel.setRating((float) hotelObject.getDouble("rating"));
                        hotelModel.setHotel_id(hotelObject.getInt("hotel_id"));
                        hotelModel.setDist(hotelObject.getInt("dist"));
                        hotelModelList.add(hotelModel);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }else {
                if (jsonStr != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray listArray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                        for (int i = 0; i < listArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject hotelObject = listArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            HotelModel hotelModel = new HotelModel();
                            hotelModel.setName(hotelObject.getString("name"));
                            hotelModel.setAddr(hotelObject.getString("addr"));
                            hotelModel.setCateg(hotelObject.getString("categ"));
                            hotelModel.setImg(CONSTANTS.server_domain+hotelObject.getString("image"));
                            hotelModel.setPrice(hotelObject.getInt("price"));
                            hotelModel.setRating((float) hotelObject.getDouble("rating"));
                            hotelModel.setHotel_id(hotelObject.getInt("hotel_id"));
                            hotelModel.setDist(hotelObject.getInt("dist"));
                            hotelModelList.add(hotelModel);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }if (orderby.equals("location")) {
                        Log.e("ll", String.valueOf(hotelModelList.get(0).getDist()));
                        Collections.sort(hotelModelList, new Comparator<HotelModel>() {
                            @Override
                            public int compare(HotelModel o1, HotelModel o2) {
                                return o1.getDist() - o2.getDist();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else if (orderby.equals("price")) {
                        Collections.sort(hotelModelList, new Comparator<HotelModel>() {
                            @Override
                            public int compare(HotelModel o1, HotelModel o2) {
                                return o1.getPrice() - o2.getPrice();
                            }
                        });
                    } else if (orderby.equals("rating")) {
                        Collections.sort(hotelModelList, new Comparator<HotelModel>() {
                            @Override
                            public int compare(HotelModel o1, HotelModel o2) {
                                return (int) (o2.getRating() * 100 - o1.getRating() * 100);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
        }
            return hotelModelList;
        }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<HotelModel> hotelModels) {
        super.onPostExecute(hotelModels);
        HotelAdapter hotelAdapter = new HotelAdapter(hotel_populate_list.this,R.layout.item_hotel,hotelModels);
        hotelPopulate.setAdapter(hotelAdapter);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(hotel_populate_list.this);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Gathering details from Internet...");
        progressDialog.show();
    }
}
```

App is not crashing but I cant see the result fetched. PLEASE NOTE IT WAS FETHING THE RESULT WHEN I WAS DOING IT THROUGH LOCALHOST

I tried to put the below in Log.e to see if json data is being fetch or not. Its not fetching and it gave me null pointer exception

```
jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(HotelURL + CONSTANTS.city+"&origin=" + CONSTANTS.origin);
```

Adding the makeServiceCall method

```
public String makeServiceCall(String reqUrl) {
    String response = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

        // read the response
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        response = convertStreamToString(in);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return response;
}

private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I checked further and this is related to webhosting blocking traffic from mobile/android. I tried with multiple hostings and unfortunately this is same for all. Is there a way I can make these calls look like they are coming from browser ?

Comment: What are u using for your api calls? (Id highly recommend using retrofit.) Can u put your makeServiceCall method code? Did u put the required permissions inside the manifest.xml?

Comment: Yes every permission is present as I mentioned it was working through localhost. Adding makeServiceCall

Comment: I think issue is with the web hosting. I think it is blocking traffic for android app but allowing for web browser

Comment: where are you getting the null pointer exception? Also, check whether any exceptions are logged in your Logcat.

Comment: As I mentioned I'm getting null pointer exception becuase no data is being returned from API call. I checked further and this is related to webhosting blocking traffic from mobile/android. Is there a way I can make these calls look like they are coming from browser ?

Answer (score 0):

The server connection uses http protocol. You will need to set https or if you need it to be http and your app is targeting Api level 28 or higher you will need to set this in your manifest:

```
<application
...
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
...>
```

If that does not work, the problem will be on server side